# How can I unserialize session data to an arbitrary variable in PHP?

Tags: php, session, serialization

I want to unserialize a `session_encode()`'d string of session data to my own array (i.e. not to `$_SESSION`.)

There doesn't appear to be an in-built function that handles this.  There's `session_decode()` but it writes directly to the `$_SESSION` super-global.  There's `unserialize()` but it returns false on `session_encode()`'d strings as they're a slightly different format.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the comments in the PHP manual's [`session_decode`](http://us.php.net/session_decode) page. It has a bunch of user functions to handle decoding a `session_encode` string manually. As far as I know, that's the only way to go.

Comment: I used the first answer on that manual page.  I've edited my post to include a direct link to that answer.

Comment: I noticed the posted solutions php.net have a serious flaw. I've contributed my own solution which avoids the use of a regular expression. I will also post it here.

Comment: The whole point of reading a session file's data manually is to *not start the session associated with it* which in the case of an SSE creates a lag bug in Blink/Chrome.

Answer (score 23):

I noticed that the posted solutions (on php.net) for manually decoding sessions are not perfect, so I've contributed a more robust solution.

The preg_match solution can never work. It's not so hard to find a case that might break unserialization.
In the case of jason-joeymail is breaks on:

```
$_SESSION["test"] = ";oops|";
```

Below you can find my solution. It doesn't use a regular expression but rather the reversibility of the serialize operation and the 'feature' that serialize ignores all further input when it thinks it's done. It's by no means a beautiful or particularly fast solution but it is a more robust solution.
I've added a deserializer for "php" and "php_binary". It should be trivial to add one for "wddx".

```
class Session {
    public static function unserialize($session_data) {
        $method = ini_get("session.serialize_handler");
        switch ($method) {
            case "php":
                return self::unserialize_php($session_data);
                break;
            case "php_binary":
                return self::unserialize_phpbinary($session_data);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported session.serialize_handler: " . $method . ". Supported: php, php_binary");
        }
    }

    private static function unserialize_php($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
                throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
            }
            $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
            $num = $pos - $offset;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num + 1;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }

    private static function unserialize_phpbinary($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            $num = ord($session_data[$offset]);
            $offset += 1;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Session::unserialize(session_encode());
```

Comment: +1 code is kinda ugly, but this is the one that worked for me, other workarounds didn't.

Comment: This is useful for anyone who wants to parse session data from the command line, because `session_decode` only works if you have an open session.

Comment: Any benchmarks compared to the following?
`$cur = session_encode(); session_decode($encoded_data); /* encoded data put into $_SESSION */ session_decode($cur); /* current $_SESSION restored */`

Comment: @Halycon Have you got the serialize method of this unserialize code?

Answer (score 4):

The custom 'php' deserialise function above can be made cleaner by avoiding the 'incrementing offset' approach in favour of gradually eating up the input session string.

I've not checked how it compares in terms of speed, but it's certainly tidier (and saves repeated calls to strlen in the while loop)

```
$r = array();
while ($i = strpos($str, '|'))
{
    $k = substr($str, 0, $i);
    $v = unserialize(substr($str, 1 + $i));
    $str = substr($str, 1 + $i + strlen(serialize($v)));
    $r[$k] = $v;
}
return $r; // session data are now in a normal array
```

Comment: @Michael Szyndel: my answer referred specifically to the 'php' handler above because that was a specific value in a "case" statement.By needlessly editing my post to start "PHP deserialise.." this detail has been lost.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler you can set

```
session.serialize_handler = php_serialize
```

Then you can use php's serialize() / unserialize() functions.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
/* storre current session */
$current_session = session_encode(); 

/* extract $other_user_session from file or database,
   into the $_SESSION global variable */
session_decode($other_user_session); 

/* use the other user session data:  $something = $_SESSION['something']; */

/* restore previous sesison info */
session_decode($current_session); /* current $_SESSION restored */
```

Comment: I like this answer as it doesn't try to parse something so easily breakable (sort of like when people look for RegEx for parsing HTML - never ends well!). My only (probably irrational) concern is setting the `$_SESSION` variable to that of another user. I don't see why it would be a problem, but it makes me nervous :v. It is though, the best solution from all that I've seen here. Quick and dirty!

Comment: Again, the point of reading a session file *manually* is to *not start the session*.

Answer (score 0):

```
function data_session_decode($data){
    $data = array_filter(explode(';',$data));
    $list_data = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $dat){
        if(!empty($dat)){
          $data[$key] = array_filter(explode('|',$dat));
          if(substr($data[$key][1], 0, 1) == 'i'){
              $list_data[$data[$key][0]] = strstr($data[$key][1], ':');
              $list_data[$data[$key][0]] = substr($list_data[$data[$key][0]], 1);
          }elseif(substr($data[$key][1], 0, 1) == 's'){
              $list_data[$data[$key][0]] = strstr($data[$key][1], '"');
              $list_data[$data[$key][0]] = substr($list_data[$data[$key][0]], 0, -1);
              $list_data[$data[$key][0]] = substr($list_data[$data[$key][0]], 1);
          }else{
              unset($data[$key]);
          }
        }
    }
    unset($data);
    return $list_data;
}
```

// HERE DATA SESSION EX:

$dataSession = 'user_name|s:8:"You Name";date|i:1459396063';

//Out

print_r($this->data_session_decode($dataSession));

Answer (score -9):

Why don't you just do something like this?

```
$myVariable = serialize($_SESSION);
$sessionCopy = unserialize($myVariable);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Because sessions are serialized in a different format to serialize/unserialize()

Comment: Well, yes, but you can set the session.serialize_handler to php_serialize. See http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler for details