# Read the session data from session storage file

Tags: php, serialization

Facing problem with `PHP unserialize()` function as titled it is throwing error.

```
unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 1781 bytes
```

I also tried the `session_decode()` which return `bool(false)`

`magic_quotes_gpc` is `Off`.

Well, I am reading content of file which is serialized. File contents looks like below.

> core|a:3:{s:23:"_session_validator_data";a:4:{s:11:"remote_addr";s:15:"117.241.113.248";s:8:"http_via";s:0:"";s:20:"http_x_forwarded_for";s:0:"";s:15:"http_user_agent";s:90:"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203
>   Firefox/3.6.13";}s:13:"session_hosts";a:1:{s:12:"";b:1;}s:8:"messages";O:34:"Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection":2:{s:12:"^@*^@_messages";a:0:{}s:20:"^@*^@_lastAddedMessage";N;}}customer|a:3:{s:23:"_session_validator_data";a:4:{s:11:"remote_addr";s:15:"117.241.113.248";s:8:"http_via";s:0:"";s:20:"http_x_forwarded_for";s:0:"";s:15:"http_user_agent";s:90:"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203
>   Firefox/3.6.13";}s:13:"session_hosts";a:1:{s:12:"";b:1;}s:19:"wishlist_item_count";i:0;}catalog|a:3:{s:23:"_session_validator_data";a:4:{s:11:"remote_addr";s:15:"117.241.113.248";s:8:"http_via";s:0:"";s:20:"http_x_forwarded_for";s:0:"";s:15:"http_user_agent";s:90:"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203
>   Firefox/3.6.13";}s:13:"session_hosts";a:1:{s:12:"";b:1;}s:8:"messages";O:34:"Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection":2:{s:12:"^@*^@_messages";a:0:{}s:20:"^@*^@_lastAddedMessage";N;}}checkout|a:3:{s:23:"_session_validator_data";a:4:{s:11:"remote_addr";s:15:"117.241.113.248";s:8:"http_via";s:0:"";s:20:"http_x_forwarded_for";s:0:"";s:15:"http_user_agent";s:90:"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203
>   Firefox/3.6.13";}s:13:"session_hosts";a:1:{s:12:"";b:1;}s:8:"messages";O:34:"Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection":2:{s:12:"^@*^@_messages";a:0:{}s:20:"^@*^@_lastAddedMessage";N;}}

my PHP code is below

```
$file='/var/www/html/products/var/session/sess_0ehb7ek0hmunqo3kq70t0t6mb0';
$contents=file_get_contents($file);
$data = unserialize($contents); 
var_dump($data);
```

I already tried the `stripslashes()` before unserializing data.
Not sure where is the problem in data. 
I can not change the mechanism of storing data in to file because this is handled by Magento for mananging session on File level.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the contents contain 3 separate variables (types core, customer, and checkout). Maybe that is causing the problem in unserialize?

Comment: @kevin:Yes, it contains. Is it problem?

Comment: I believe (not exactly positive) that you can only [de]serialize one variable at once. Have you tried splitting them up and unserializing those?

Comment: Please see my solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530761/how-can-i-unserialize-session-data-to-an-arbitrary-variable-in-php/9843773#9843773

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to decode session data, use `session_decode` (see the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php)). `unserialize` only decodes single variables, not session data.

You can do something like:

```
$file = '/var/www/html/products/var/session/sess_ciktos8icvk11grtpkj3u610o3';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
session_start();
session_decode($contents);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Tried this returns bool(false)

Comment: try to do session_start() before decoding, then inspect $_SESSION.

Comment: @StasM: After adding session_start(); it is returning true but the string is also converted in numeric 1.

Comment: if it returns true, the values should be in $_SESSION. What is in $_SESSION after the call?

Comment: @StasM: Nothing in the $_SESSION and StasM I this is not resuming the session how it can show me the data in $_SESSION

Comment: While this works, and is the only officially supported way, it overwrites your existing session.

Comment: This only works for the *active session*, not an opened *session file*.

Answer (score 8):

Use this class:

```
    <?php
class Session {
    public static function unserialize($session_data) {
        $method = ini_get("session.serialize_handler");
        switch ($method) {
            case "php":
                return self::unserialize_php($session_data);
                break;
            case "php_binary":
                return self::unserialize_phpbinary($session_data);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unsupported session.serialize_handler: " . $method . ". Supported: php, php_binary");
        }
    }

    private static function unserialize_php($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
                throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
            }
            $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
            $num = $pos - $offset;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num + 1;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }

    private static function unserialize_phpbinary($session_data) {
        $return_data = array();
        $offset = 0;
        while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
            $num = ord($session_data[$offset]);
            $offset += 1;
            $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
            $offset += $num;
            $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
            $return_data[$varname] = $data;
            $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
        }
        return $return_data;
    }
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
<?php
Session::unserialize(file_get_contents($sessionSavePath."/".$sessionFileName);
?>
```

Thats Work!

Comment: Linking to the source for this comment (credit where credit is due!): http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php#108037

Comment: Please show how to set `$sessionSavePath` and `$sessionFileName`

Comment: @Jonathan, you read $sessionSavePath parameter value from php.ini file and $sessionFileName parameter is generated with sessionid. Those options get from php.ini file.

Answer (score 6):

That is not legal PHP serialized data, that's PHP session data.

PHP session data uses the serialized format internally, but it is *not* serialized data itself.

The only thing that can safely and sanely read session data is PHP's session code.  It is *sometimes* possible to read it using a regular expression and some creative editing, but you can not rely upon those methods.

**If you need data out of a user's session, your best bet is to write a custom session wrapper and let it do the work when the data itself changes** rather than try and work with the data after the fact.

(I'm not talking about custom session-writing code, I'm talking about a class that you would use instead of using `$_SESSION` directly.)

Comment: I have tried all possible way to get the All current session on my site. Now , this is the last option I have, reading the current active session data from file and processing them.

Answer (score 6):

Following can be a way to read session data from session file

```
//$file='/var/www/html/products/var/session/sess_ciktos8icvk11grtpkj3u610o3';
$sSessId = 'ciktos8icvk11grtpkj3u610o3';
session_id($sSessId);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 2):

check out, this might click you something

```
function read($filename)
{
    session_save_path("/tmp/tst");
    session_start();
    echo    $sCurrentFile = "/tmp/tst/sess_".session_id();
    $sFileToRead = $filename;
    if( !file_exists($sFileToRead) || !$sessionData=(string)@file_get_contents($sFileToRead) )
    {
        echo "file does not exist";
    }

    $fh = fopen($sCurrentFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $sessionData);
    fclose($fh);
    $_SESSION["mytest"] = 444; 
    print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try
[Read Session Data from Session File](http://tools.resplace.net/php/session-decoder/)

Comment: Note that [link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged. Answers should be the end-point of a search for a 
solution instead of pointing to a link which often becomes stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.