# How to open a .sess file?

Tags: linux, windows, file, session, fileopenpicker

I have some session files of the extension `*.sess`. How do I open it on Linux/Windows? I tried using normal text editors but I get partial junk values and partial actual text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are trying to read the PHP session files. If so, please go through the below link which is reading the session files using simple PHP code:
[Read the session data from session storage file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698432/read-the-session-data-from-session-storage-file)

Comment: Nope, not working. It's just printing an empty array.