# Convert array to string to write to session file

Tags: php, arrays, session

How can I convert an array to a serialized string that I can write to a session file? This is being done in a command line script, not in a browser, so I can not use `session_write_close()`.

I have tried `serialize()` function and that does not convert it properly (see below).

**Notice:** I already know I shouldn't manually write to a session file, and I should use the database for session data instead.

### If I use `file_get_contents()` on the session file I get:

```
user_id|i:4;user_first_name|s:9:"FirstName";user_last_name|s:8:"LastName";user_last_login|s:10:"2016-06-03";random_data|a:4:{s:2:"ID";i:83;s:3:"URL";a:1:{i:0;s:23:"https://www.example.com";}s:4:"Date";s:10:"2016-06-08";s:4:"Year";s:4:"2016";}
```

### I convert it to an array with some PHP and get:

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [user_first_name] => FirstName
    [user_last_name] => LastName
    [user_last_login] => 2016-06-03
    [random_data] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 83
            [URL] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.example.com
                )

            [Date] => 2016-06-08
            [Year] => 2016 
        )

)
```

### Now I need to convert the array back into a string for the session file:

```
user_id|i:4;user_first_name|s:9:"FirstName";user_last_name|s:8:"LastName";user_last_login|s:10:"2016-06-03";random_data|a:4:{s:2:"ID";i:83;s:3:"URL";a:1:{i:0;s:23:"https://www.example.com";}s:4:"Date";s:10:"2016-06-08";s:4:"Year";s:4:"2016";}
```

### I used Serialize() and got this (not the same as what came out of the session file):

```
a:12:{s:7:"user_id";i:4;s:15:"user_first_name";s:9:"FirstName";s:14:"user_last_name";s:8:"LastName";s:15:"user_last_login";s:10:"2016-06-03";s:11:"random_data";a:24:{s:2:"ID";i:83;s:3:"URL";a:1:{i:0;s:23:"https://www.example.com";}s:3:"API";N;s:4:"Date";s:10:"2016-06-08";s:4:"Year";s:4:"2016";}}
```

**EDIT:** It has to be the same format as the original string format (from `file_get_contents()`) because when I insert the `serialize()` string format it logs me out of the website.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php functions [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to do that. By the way, the advantage of this way, that it saves type of, at least, standard php objects. For example, this code:

```
$o = new DateTime();
print_r(unserialize(serialize($o)));
```

returns `DateTime Object`

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried `serialize()`. I have updated my question.

Comment: What do you call correct and not correct? Why do you want your own format of the string instead of system supported one?

Comment: Well, it's just not the same format as what originally comes out of the session file. I've edited my question again to show that.

Comment: @Draven look there. It maybe you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698432/read-the-session-data-from-session-storage-file

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON format:

json_encode(array);

For decode:

json_decode($json_string);