# Symfony2 & PdoSessionStorage : how to add fields in database session table?

Tags: session, symfony, pdo

I am using FOSUserBundle to manage users, and sessions are saved in database thanks to PdoSessionStorage.

I would like to add fields in my session table :

- user_id : which is a foreign key referencing the ID of logged user
- ip : IP address of the user logged in
- end_time : the time when the user has logged out

Here is my app/config/config.yml file :

```
framework:
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        auto_start: true
        lifetime: 72000
        storage_id: session.storage.pdo

parameters:
    pdo.db_options:
        db_table: session
        db_id_col: session_id
        db_data_col: value
        db_time_col: time

services:
    doctrine.dbal.default.wrapped_connection:
        factory_service: doctrine.dbal.default_connection
        factory_method: getWrappedConnection
        class: PDO
    session.storage.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\SessionStorage\PdoSessionStorage
        arguments: [@doctrine.dbal.default.wrapped_connection, %session.storage.options%, %pdo.db_options%]
```

How can I do that ?

Do I need to extend PdoSessionStorage class ?

If so, how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply extend `PdoSessionStorage` to add your infos. You are free to add any dependency to the  `session.storage.pdo`.

About the User ID, you don't have to do it, it's already in the session data (you will have to decode them).

Comment: for unserializing the sess_data the class provided here was useful to me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843773/2848530