# Decode Symfony 4 PdoSessionHandler-based data?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm using sessions with a PdoSessionHandler. Is there a way to deserialize and instantiate each row of the sess_data into a Session object that I can inspect?

Something like session_deocode() in plain php?

Comment: Can you elaborate? By default session data is simply stored as a serialized php object, so running `unserialize($row['sess_data'])` will return the data in a way that you can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @drumann! I figured out trimming the prefix "_sf2_attributes|" from sess_data, got me the deserialize version of the Symfony 4 session i.e.

```
unserialize(trim($sess_data,"_sf2_attributes|"))
```

Comment: more robust solution for decoding a session string can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843773/2848530